# Xamarin Forms Listview: Deselecting selected item by checking with OnTapped Event

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, deselect

I will be able to deselect my item when i click second time on it.
When I tap an item the background color changed to blue. I want that the background gets the default color when I tap second time to the same item from the list.
Here can you find my code but it isn't working.

### XAML

```
<StackLayout Margin="5,0,5,0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
    <Frame Style="{StaticResource StandardFrameStyle}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
      <ListView x:Name="lst_pickList" ItemSelected="OnItemSelected" ItemTapped="OnItemTapped" ItemsSource="{Binding PickList}" HasUnevenRows="True" Style="{StaticResource StandardListViewStyle}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
              <ViewCell.View>
                <Grid x:Name="grd_pickList" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" >
                  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                  <Label x:Name="lbl_comment" Text="Comment:" FontAttributes="Bold" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource StandardLabelStyle}" />
                  <Label x:Name="lbl_itemNo" Text="ItemNo:" FontAttributes="Bold" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource StandardLabelStyle}" />
                  <Label x:Name="lbl_description" Text="Description:" FontAttributes="Bold" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource StandardLabelStyle}" />
                  <Label x:Name="lbl_restant" Text="Restant:" FontAttributes="Bold" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource StandardLabelStyle}" />

                  <Label x:Name="lbl_comment_binding" Text="{Binding Comment}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource StandardLabelStyle}" />
                  <Label x:Name="lbl_itemNo_binding" Text="{Binding ItemNo}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource StandardLabelStyle}" />
                  <Label x:Name="lbl_description_binding" Text="{Binding Description}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource StandardLabelStyle}" />
                  <Label x:Name="lbl_restant_binding" Text="{Binding Restant}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource StandardLabelStyle}" />
                </Grid>
              </ViewCell.View>
            </ViewCell>
          </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
      </ListView>
    </Frame>
  </StackLayout>
```

### CodeBehind

```
public void OnItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs args)
    {
        var newSelectedPick = args.Item as Pick;

        if(selectedPick != null && selectedPick.Id == newSelectedPick.Id)
        {
            lst_pickList.SelectedItem = null;
        }
        else
        {
            selectedPick = newSelectedPick;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a `boolean` property on your `Pick` object named `IsSelected` ,then `Bind` it your `grd_pickList`'s `BackgroundColor` with a converter.

i.e:

**//Xaml**

```
<ListView.Resources>
  <ResourceDictionary>
    <local:BgConverter x:Key="BgConverter"/>
  </ResourceDictionary>
</ListView.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="grd_pickList" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="{Binding IsSelected,Converter={StaticResource BgConverter}}" >
```

**//Converter**

```
class BgConverter : IValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is bool &&(bool)value)
            return Color.Blue;
         else
            return Color.White;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

**//Xaml.cs**

```
public void OnItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs args)
{
    var itm = args.Item as Pick;
    itm.IsSelected = !itm.IsSelected;
}
```

**Important**: Be Sure IsSelected Property Triggers `OnPropertyChanged` event.